# How to find $P( \exists n \geq 1~such~that~S_n=-8)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Suppose $X_1,X_2,..$ are i.i.d random variables, taking only the values $-1,0,1,2$, with

$P(X_1 =-1) = 0.5\\
P(X_1 =0) = 0.1\\
P(X_1 =1) = 0.2\\
P(X_1 =2) = 0.2
$

Use martingale techniques to compute $P( \exists n \geq 1~such~that~S_n=-8)$.

I understand the symmetric and asymmetric random walk questions.
[A question from the martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4405889/a-question-from-the-martingale)

I am not sure how to start this problem or how it satisfy the Optional Stopping theorem. Can anyone give me some hints to solve this problem?

Comment: Is $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$?

Comment: Yes. $S_n = X_1+X_2+..+X_n$.

Comment: Why do you have to use a martingale technique?  It seems there is a solution of the form $p^8$ where $p$ is an easily-found root of a cubic equation.  I suspect the answer is $\frac{36913}{16} - 1233\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}$

Comment: @Henry How did you get this answer?

Comment: It looks as if there is upwards drift so the probability will be less than $1$.  If you call the probability of reaching a point $k$ lower $q_k$ then you may have $q_k=0.5q_{k-1}+0.1q_k+0.2q_{k+1}+0.2q_{k+2}$ with $q_0=1$ and this looks as if it has a solution of the form $q_k=p^k$ for a suitable $p$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\tau_j=\inf\{n:S_n=j\}$. We want an $r \neq 1$ s.t. $E[r^{S_n}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]=r^{S_{n-1}}$ and $(r^{S_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale. We then compute
$$E[r^{S_n-S_{n-1}}|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]=E[r^{X_1}]=p_{-1}r^{-1}+p_0+p_1 r+p_2r^2=1\implies r^*\approx 0.871$$
Notice that $r^{S_n}$ converges to $0$ a.s. We use optional stopping:
$$1=E[r^{S_{\tau_{-b}\wedge n}}]=r^{-b}P(\tau_{-b}<n)+\underbrace{E[r^{S_n}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_{-b}\geq n\}}]}_{\textrm{DCT }\to 0}$$
Thus $P(\tau_{-b}<\infty)=r^{b}$ by continuity of measures. The solution has the same form suggested by @Henry in the comments.